# how to post list of multipart form-data to asp.net web api action

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I am working on asp.net Web API. I am trying to save a list of complex classes that has properties of type either image data or text data. I have two classes,

**Question Class**

```
public  class Question
{
   public int QuestionId { get; set; }
   public string Text { get; set; }
   public string Type { get; set; }
}
```

**Response Class**

```
public  class Response
{
    public int ResponseId { get; set; }
    public int QuestionId { get; set; }
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public string ResponseText { get; set; }
}
```

Here is how the Application form would look like,

```
--------------------------------------
1, Question Text (Label)
   Response (TextBox Control)
--------------------------------------
2, Question Text (Label)
   Response (File upload control)
--------------------------------------
3, Question Text (Label)
   Response (TextArea)
-------------------------------------
4, Question Text (Label)
   Response (Either File upload,Textbox other control)
-------------------------------------
       | Submit Answers Button |
-------------------------------------
```

When user clicks on submit answers button, All the page data will be posted to a web api action.

If all are simple text boxes i.e. simple form-data, then i post data (List) to web api like in json is,

```
[{"QuestionId":1,"UserId":321,"ResponseText":"Hello"},{"QuestionId":2,"UserId":321,"ResponseText":"Great"},{"QuestionId":3,"UserId":321,"ResponseText":"Simple"}]
```

in web api,

```
public HttpResponseMessage SubmitAnswers(HttpRequestMessage request,List<Response>    responses)
{
....
....
....
}
```

But here in my case, i have multipart form-data and also i have to post multiple form data i.e. each question with response is treated as a single form, so how could we post list of multipart form-data to asp.net web api action. Please Guide me.

Comment: Why are you using web api for this and not an MVC controller action, which would be much simpler.

Comment: Well i need to give the backend support via web api for iphone app, their app have the questions form and they post data to web api.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked into using `MultipartFormDataProvider` where the request is a multipart request having 'formurlencoded' data + files?...but if your request is like 'json' data + files, then you can use `MultipartMemoryStreamProvider`...if files are huge and memory usage is a concern, you can create a custom `MultipartStreamProvider`...

Answer (score 0):

This is code is not yet tested, but it should give you an idea to get you started.

```
// Create a MultipartFormDataContent object
var multipartContent = new MultipartFormDataContent();

int counter = 0;
foreach (var question in questions)
{
    // Serialize each "question" item found in "questions"
    var questionJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(question, 
    new JsonSerializerSettings
    {
        ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver()
    });

    // Add each serialized question to the multipart object
    multipartContent.Add(new StringContent(questionJson, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json"), "question" + counter);
    counter++;
}

// Post a petition with a  multipart/form-data body
var response = new HttpClient()
    .PostAsync("http://multiformserver.com:53908/api/send", multipartContent)
    .Result;

var responseContent = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
```

I suggest you use [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) to see by yourself the contents of the petition and the response. You can find more information about how to use Fiddler at [Fiddler's Documentation](http://docs.telerik.com/fiddler/configure-fiddler/tasks/configurefiddler) website.